# Getting Ext Model Data from TreeModel

Tags: extjs, extjs4.2

When adding data to a ExtJS TreeStore, the data is transformed into a TreeModel. When you call getData() on these TreeModels, it returns not just the fields specified in the original Ext.data.Model for the object, but also a bunch of other fields like qshowDelay, isFirst, allowDrag,...

What is the best way to get rid of all of these extra added fields so that I can POST just the fields specified in the original Ext.data.Model for the object?

Answer (score 1):

The `persist` property is `false` for the added fields. So if you only want the modified fields for posting, you can use the model's `modified` property, and it will not include the added fields. If you want the data from all the original fields you can do something like:

```
   var fields = Ext.Array.filter(MyModel.getFields(), function(field){
       return field.persist!=false;
   });
   var data = Ext.copyTo(data, record.data, Ext.Array.pluck(fields, 'name'));
```